# Hiding TreeView Columns In Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I've created a TreeView but I want to be able to hide certain columns when I call specific functions. So this TreeView gets initially created but when I call a function lets say all of the columns are hidden except for [trackArtist]. How do I do this? I can sort of get it to work by rewriting parts of the TreeView  (the columns I want to appear) within the function but that seems awfully redundant.

```
def some_function(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame)
        ttk.Style().configure("displayField", background="#850664", foreground="#000000", fieldbackground="#FFFFFF")
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.stationBuilderMenu, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.stationBuilderMenu, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set)
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

        self.tree["columns"]=("trackNumber", "trackTitle", "artistCat", "artistDisplay", "trackArtist", "album",
                              "albumLabel", "composer", "year", "trackDuration", "albumAsin", "albumItunes", "ISRC",
                              "filename", "albumCoverName", "notes")
        self.tree.column("trackNumber", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("trackTitle", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("artistCat", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("artistDisplay", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("trackArtist", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("album", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("albumLabel", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("composer", stretch=0, anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("year", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("trackDuration", stretch=0, anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("albumAsin", stretch=0, anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("albumItunes", stretch=0, anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("filename", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("albumCoverName", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
        self.tree.column("notes", stretch=0, anchor=N)
        self.tree.heading("trackNumber", text="Track Number")
        self.tree.heading("trackTitle", text="Track Title")
        self.tree.heading("artistCat", text="Artist CAT")
        self.tree.heading("artistDisplay", text="Artist Display")
        self.tree.heading("trackArtist", text="Track Artist")
        self.tree.heading("album", text="Album")
        self.tree.heading("albumLabel", text="Album Label")
        self.tree.heading("composer", text="Composer")
        self.tree.heading("year", text="Year")
        self.tree.heading("trackDuration", text="Track Duration")
        self.tree.heading("albumAsin", text="Album ASIN")
        self.tree.heading("albumItunes", text="Album iTunes")
        self.tree.heading("ISRC", text="ISRC")
        self.tree.heading("filename", text="File Name")
        self.tree.heading("albumCoverName", text="Album Cover Filename")
        self.tree.heading("notes", text="Notes")
        self.tree.grid(in_=self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame, row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        ysb.grid(in_=self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame, row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        xsb.grid(in_=self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame, row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

This is the hack code I've thrown together. Doesn't work very well.

```
def some_other_function(self):
    # things happen
    # inefficient code below
    self.tree["columns"]=("artistCat", "artistDisplay")
    self.tree.column("artistCat", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
    self.tree.column("artistDisplay", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
    self.tree.heading("artistCat", text="Artist CAT")
    self.tree.heading("artistDisplay", text="Artist Display")

class StationBuilder():
    def __init__(self, master, importTree):
        self.importTree = importTree
        self.stationBuilderMenu = master
        self.stationBuilderMenu = Toplevel(master)
        self.stationBuilderMenuTopFrame = Frame(self.stationBuilderMenu, bg="#BFC0C2", bd=1, relief=RIDGE)
        self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame = Frame(self.stationBuilderMenu)
        self.stationBuilderMenuBottomFrame = Frame(self.stationBuilderMenu, bg="#BFC0C2", bd=1, relief=RIDGE)
        self.stationBuilderMenuRightFrame = Frame(self.stationBuilderMenu, bg="#BFC0C2", bd=1, relief=RIDGE, width=300)
        self.stationBuilderMenu.wm_title("AccuAdmin - toStationBuilder")
        self.stationBuilderMenu.configure(background="#BFC0C2")
        self.currentTrack = 0
        self.currentState = 0
        self.artistObjectId = ""
        self.albumObjectId = ""
        self.composerObjectId = ""
        self.trackObjectId = ""
        self.treeId = ""
        self.states = [self.search_artist, self.search_album, self.search_composer, self.search_track]

        self.match = Button(self.stationBuilderMenuBottomFrame, text="Match", highlightbackground="#BFC0C2",
                            command=self.exists)
        self.createNewObject = Button(self.stationBuilderMenuBottomFrame, text="", highlightbackground="#BFC0C2",
                                      command=self.create_new_object)
        self.currentObject = Label(self.stationBuilderMenuTopFrame, text="", font=("default", 50), bg="#BFC0C2",
                                   fg="#FFFFFF")
        self.currentlyProcessedTrackHeading = Label(self.stationBuilderMenuRightFrame, text="- Current Track -",
                                                    bg="#BFC0C2")
        self.currentlyProcessedTrack = Label(self.stationBuilderMenuRightFrame, text="", bg="#BFC0C2")

        self.create_potential_match_display()

        self.stationBuilderMenuBottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        self.stationBuilderMenuTopFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.stationBuilderMenuRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.currentObject.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(25, 0))
        self.currentlyProcessedTrackHeading.pack(side=TOP)
        self.currentlyProcessedTrack.pack(side=TOP)
        self.match.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=(0, 25))
        self.createNewObject.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(25, 0))

        self.states[self.currentState](importedTracks[self.currentTrack])
        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.find_selection)
```

Comment: Please include the scrolling environment so that this can be verified / tested

Comment: This opensource project might help you a lot: https://github.com/talcs/tals_python_task_diary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do so by using

`self.tree["displaycolumns"]=("artistCat", "artistDisplay")`

Found on the [Documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html).

To display all but one, you can build it up in a for loop

```
exclusionlist=[...]
displaycolumns=[]
for col in tree["columns"]:
    if not "%s"%col in exclusionlist:
        displaycolumns.append(col)
tree["displaycolumns"]=displaycolumns
```

Find below working code that does not mess up data. **ONLY USING `tree["displaycolumns"]=[...]`**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
    #
    # FILE:     SO_33290969.py
    # CREATED:  2015-10-28
    __CHANGED__="2015-11-02 17:54:55"
    __VERSION__=1.1

    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

    from Tkinter import *

    class some_Class(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.master=args[0]
            self.grid()

            self.some_function()

        def some_function(self):
            self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
            ttk.Style().configure("displayField", background="#850664", foreground="#000000", fieldbackground="#FFFFFF")
            ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.tree.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
            xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, command=self.tree.xview, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
            self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set)
            self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

            self.tree["columns"]=("trackNumber", "trackTitle", "artistCat", "artistDisplay", "trackArtist", "album",
                              "albumLabel", "composer", "year", "trackDuration", "albumAsin", "albumItunes", "ISRC",
                              "filename", "albumCoverName", "notes")
            self.tree.column("trackNumber", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("trackTitle", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("artistCat", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("artistDisplay", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("trackArtist", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("album", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("albumLabel", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("composer", stretch=0, anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("year", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("trackDuration", stretch=0, anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("albumAsin", stretch=0, anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("albumItunes", stretch=0, anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("filename", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("albumCoverName", stretch=0,  anchor=N)
            self.tree.column("notes", stretch=0, anchor=N)
            self.tree.heading("trackNumber", text="Track Number")
            self.tree.heading("trackTitle", text="Track Title")
            self.tree.heading("artistCat", text="Artist CAT")
            self.tree.heading("artistDisplay", text="Artist Display")
            self.tree.heading("trackArtist", text="Track Artist")
            self.tree.heading("album", text="Album")
            self.tree.heading("albumLabel", text="Album Label")
            self.tree.heading("composer", text="Composer")
            self.tree.heading("year", text="Year")
            self.tree.heading("trackDuration", text="Track Duration")
            self.tree.heading("albumAsin", text="Album ASIN")
            self.tree.heading("albumItunes", text="Album iTunes")
            self.tree.heading("ISRC", text="ISRC")
            self.tree.heading("filename", text="File Name")
            self.tree.heading("albumCoverName", text="Album Cover Filename")
            self.tree.heading("notes", text="Notes")
            self.tree.grid(in_=self.master, row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
            ysb.grid(in_=self.master, row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
            xsb.grid(in_=self.master, row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
            self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.loadUI()

        def loadUI(self, event=None):
            tk.Button(self.master, text="filter columns", command=self.some_other_function).grid(row=2, column=0)
            tk.Button(self.master, text="load data", command=self.loadData).grid(row=2, column=1)

        def loadData(self, event=None):
            self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(["data%s"%col for col in self.tree["columns"]]))

        def some_other_function(self):
            if len(self.tree["displaycolumns"]) != 2:
                print("Hiding Columns")
                self.tree["displaycolumns"]=("artistCat", "artistDisplay")
            else:
                print("Showing all columns")
                self.tree["displaycolumns"]=self.tree["columns"]

            print("Visible:   %s"%','.join([ "%s"%col for col in self.tree["displaycolumns"] ]))
            print("Available: %s"%','.join([ "%s"%col for col in self.tree["columns"] ]))
            print("Done.")

    if __name__=="__main__":
            root=tk.Tk()
            app=some_Class(root)
            app.grid()
            root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried doing that. It breaks my tree. I lose the ability to scroll and it messes up the way it it placed in the window.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot test agains that issue as your posted code above does not include the "stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame" - so checking against the scrolling issue is not possible.

Comment: Good solution. Works on its own but unfortunately is still not working with my code. I have no idea why.

Before:
http://s212.photobucket.com/user/TwilightMoon777/media/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-18%20at%202.46.06%20PM.png.html

After:
http://s212.photobucket.com/user/TwilightMoon777/media/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-18%20at%202.44.58%20PM.png.html

I'm guessing that it may have something to do with placement on my use of frames.

Comment: Can you give us more of your code to figure out your implementation errors/issues?

Comment: For me it looks like you are missing `grid_columnconfigure(column=... , weight=1)` Calls or `sticky` Arguments when gridding...

Comment: Figured it out. Had to change this line

self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
to
self.stationBuilderMenuMiddleFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

Thanks for all of your help R4PH43L!

Comment: You are welcome.  Be careful using different geometry Managers, as this may lead to errors

Answer (score 6):

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(srchFrame, columns=("ID #","Abbreviation","Name"),     height=5) 

tree.heading('#1', text='ID #', anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading('#2', text='Abbrev', anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading('#3', text='Name', anchor=tk.CENTER)
#set width to zero for column zero in order to hide it
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=60, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=160, anchor=tk.W)
tree.insert("", "end", "", values=("1","US","United States"))
tree.grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Comment: Please describe your solution. Why will this solve the problem?

Comment: By setting width = 0 (zero) to column zero (the first column in the tree view) it will only show the subsequent following columns.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my:

```
self.listaCli = ttk.Treeview(treeframe, height=3,
                       column=('col1', 'col2', 'col3'),
                      )

# create header of columns
self.listaCli.heading("#0", text="")  # do not have a column associated
self.listaCli.heading("#1", text="Id") #  id is hiding)
self.listaCli.heading("#2", text="Patient", command=self.some command)
self.listaCli.heading("#3", text="Gender",  command=self.some command)

# column criation
self.listaCli.column('#0', width=0, stretch="no")
self.listaCli.column('#1', width=0, stretch="no")  #  width=0, stretch="no" --> hide 'Id" and first column
self.listaCli.column('#2', width=200)  # Patient
self.listaCli.column('#3', width=4)  # gender
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
tree.heading("1", text="")

tree.heading("2", text="Name",command = lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "2", False))

tree.heading("3", text="POli Number",command = lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "3", False))

tree.heading("4", text="Number Of People",command = lambda: treeview_sort_column(tree, "4", False))

tree.heading("5", text="Ticket Number",command = lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "5", False))

tree.heading("6", text="Final amount",command = lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "6", False))

tree.heading("7", text="Username",command = lambda : treeview_sort_column(tree, "7", False))

tree["displaycolumns"]=("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
```

Comment: Downvote - contextless, no description, and doesn't match the question. This code sets displaycolumns but in no way "hides certain columns" at required times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. Totally precise. I wonder how you got 2 downvotes. While the other throw `self` at you, you just answered to the point. Thank you again